# Receive Java http response body over second web service

Tags: java, web-services, post, http-post

[image]

I have 2 web services - created with Java Servlets. The client app sends an XML to `Web Service A`. That service takes the xml and sends it to `Web Service B`. The `Web Service B` should respond with a body to my `Web Service A`, but how can I send that response to the client?

Comment: asynchronous or synchronous?

Comment: depends upon the complexity of the solutions and implementation. In the worst case synchronous might be ok, in the best case asynchronous :). The computationtime on Web Service A would be just few ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a quick synchronous transaction (round trip), The client's call when it sends file-A.xml to the WSA can be held until WSA receives a response from WSB, and send it as part of it's response.

In an asynchronous case, WSA would need to communicate with the Client if it is able to call it, or perhaps store the response, and wait for the Client to retrieve it at a later time.  This may involve the Client polling WSA in case the WSB response is not available yet.